# I reset my laptop and now Steam games are all missing

Tags: steam

I reset my pc and didn't expect anything to happen to my Steam account. I had a ton of games on there that were very expensive. I re-downloaded Steam on my now-reset laptop. When I looked at my profile and Steam purchase history, it was empty. I don't know how to recover the games and money I had on there.

--

As a little update I've done research about this over the weeks and recovered the old steam files I had but still wasn't able to get them on the account. I logged into all the steam accounts I have and all of them don't have a purchase history or friends. I will just save up the money and start up fresh and try to get the progress I had back as well. Thanks to everyone who tried to help but nothing is really working so I just give up.

Comment: When you "Reset" the PC, exactly what did you do?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin probably Reset as in Recovery Options: [How to refresh, reset, or restore your PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-refresh-reset-or-restore-your-pc-51391d9a-eb0a-84a7-69e4-c2c1fbceb8dd).

Comment: Can we presume your copies of the game were purchased and licenced to yourself on that hardware in a regular manner? And that those licences are still valid? Just askin'...

Comment: @Theraot How about "probably" whatever you like, on your own machine?  Meanwhile if you're certain that's what 김수민 meant, why not explain how you know that?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin What do we know? OP did something called "Reset" and had to re-download Steam, and the games are missing. What I posted fulfills that description. Resetting the PC as in Recovery Options, and I quote the linked article "reinstall Windows but delete your files, settings, and apps—except for the apps that came with your PC." - Now, I cannot know for certain. For all I know OP is telling lies. And this conversation devolves in whether or not knowledge at posteriori is possible and if whether or not there is any value in arguing. Which is all off-topic, of course.

Comment: Reset can be an ambiguous translation in some languages, for example in Portuguese (not likely the case here but just making the point it can happen), "reset" is often translated to "reinicializar", but that word is more commonly used to mean "restart", so it could mean either reset or restart when translated from PT back to English. Point being asking clarification on what is meant by "reset" would be totally valid on the internet even if it isn't ambiguous in English.

Comment: @Theraot You do not know that OP did something called "Reset"… only that OP described something as "I reset my pc".

If you think "reset" has only one meaning, why not explain? You Posted an assumption based on guesswork. My Post might seem strange to your mind-set but rather than assumptions or guesses, it sought to find out what actually happened.

If "this conversation devolves in whether or not knowledge at posteriori" worked in English or pig-Latin, I'd still hope everyone saw both what you don't know and what kind of thinking led you to speculate "For all I know OP is telling lies."

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin i resetted it deleting all files because i had alot of probloms with my computer, i didn't think steam would've deleted all my games so i can't get them back. I tried to get files back and even then i can't add the games then.

Comment: @Theraot i resetted the whole pc leaving no apps because i had alot of problems for some reasons. I didn't know it would make me lose the games(which was honestly stupid of me) but i'm not lying and was very upset about this because i'm a teenager and can't get them.

Answer (score 103):

Here are some possibilities:

- You are signed into the wrong account (unlikely but can't leave this
  out)
- You have filtered out games that are not ready to play (click the
  small play icon above the game list to toggle this)
- You were previously accessing games via Steam Family Sharing and need
  to re-authorize your computer to access those games
- I notice your username is Korean. It seems unlikely but *possibly*, all the games you had have been region-blocked (Korea is particularly strict with games)

If those are not the case, have a look at [this Steam guide](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5168-EUIA-6643) for more options.

Comment: Since they mentioned that the _purchase history_ is empty, I would strongly suspect tuer first option. This can help even with experienced users! Family-shared games would have no reason ever showing there either.

Comment: @Kroltan no i'm sure it's my account but il look into this again.

Comment: @JoshuaBizley thank you for the help but the last option won't be the case because i currently don't live in Korea

Comment: As for the fourth possibility, that wouldn't happen. Even if any game got region blocked **after** steam user purchased the game, they would still be able to download and play without any issue. I've experienced enough to know this... sadly.

Answer (score -1):

When a steam game has been unresponsive and a reset on the computer is necessary, this may set the steam settings back to defaults.
Therefore, If you had configured steam to have a custom Library folders where some of your games are installed, this will not be seen by steam.

You can recover the games back by going to:

**Settings > Downloads > Steam Library Folders**

Then just add your old custom Library folders which contains the other games.

Comment: I don't see how this explains the missing purchased games.